# Adding multiple objects to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

I have the following iteration:

```
historialServicios = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

// Parse and loop through the JSON
for (dictionary in messageArray) {
    //datos de nivel objects
    NSString * code = [dictionary objectForKey:@"code"];
    NSString * date = [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];

    //datos de nivel client
    NSDictionary *level2Dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"client"];
    id someObject = [level2Dict objectForKey:@"email"];

    NSLog(@"NOMBRE===%@",someObject);
    NSString * email = someObject;
    NSLog(@"EMAIL=%@",email);
    NSLog(@"CODE=%@",code);
    NSLog(@"DATE=%@",date);

    //insertamos objetos en diccionario historialServicios
}
```

The iteration is looping inside the root node of a json tree and also inside a child node "client".

What I need is to create a NSMutableArray of dictionaries. Each dictionary has to include the retrieved objects from each iteration, in this case the keys are code, data and email. Code and data from the root node, and email from the child node.

Following the example, each dictionary should be an object with the keys and values:

KEYS         VALUES
code         NSString code
date         NSString date
email        NSString email

How can I perform this way to create the NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
historialServicios = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
array = [NSMutableArray new];

// Parse and loop through the JSON
for (dictionary in messageArray) {
    //datos de nivel objects
    NSString * code = [dictionary objectForKey:@"code"];
    NSString * date = [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];

    //datos de nivel client
    NSDictionary *level2Dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"client"];
    id someObject = [level2Dict objectForKey:@"email"];

    // ADDING TO ARRAY
    [array addObject:@{@"code": code, @"date": date, @"email":someObject}];

    NSLog(@"NOMBRE===%@",someObject);
    NSString * email = someObject;
    NSLog(@"EMAIL=%@",email);
    NSLog(@"CODE=%@",code);
    NSLog(@"DATE=%@",date);

    //insertamos objetos en diccionario historialServicios
}
```